# Sony Wifi Disabled (Hard Blocked)

Tags: networking, wireless, atheros, sony, wifi-hardware-switch

My computer model is Sony SVE15137CXW. Wifi is disabled by hard block. I cannot disable airplane mode to turn on Wifi. [airplane mode's screen photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNVb6.png) I tried solutions which are in this link: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181558, but it did not solve my problem totally. Wifi is still disabled by hard block. It solved soft block problem only. Can you help me? Thank you.

```
sudo lshw -c network

    *-network ETKİSİZLEŞTİRİLDİ
       açıklama: Kablosuz arayüz
       ürün: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       üretici: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       mantıksal ad: wlp1s0
       sürüm: 01
       serial: b8:76:3f:e6:e8:a3
       genişlik: 64 bits
       saat: 33MHz
       kapasiteler: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom eternet physical wireless
       yapılandırma: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=5.4.0-58-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       kaynaklar: irq:16 bellek:c0600000-c067ffff bellek:c0680000-c068ffff
  *-network
       açıklama: Eternet interface
       ürün: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       üretici: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       mantıksal ad: enp3s0
       sürüm: 07
       serial: 30:f9:ed:d5:98:2a
       kapasite: 1Gbit/s
       genişlik: 64 bits
       saat: 33MHz
       kapasiteler: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list eternet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       yapılandırma: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       kaynaklar: irq:18 ioport:2000(boyut=256) bellek:c0404000-c0404fff bellek:c0400000-c0403fff
  *-network
       açıklama: Eternet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@3:1
       mantıksal ad: usb0
       serial: de:4c:ff:a0:4d:39
       kapasiteler: eternet physical
       yapılandırma: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.134 link=yes multicast=yes

rfkill list all

    0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Comment: Did you try `sudo rfkill unblock all` ?

Comment: @N0rbert Yes, I did, but it did not work also.

Comment: "Hard blocked" means that there is a hardware switch on your system that is turned off.  Software can't fix this

Comment: @waltinator I know that, but there is no hardware switch on my computer. I used Windows on this PC, and the computer was crashed. After that, I installed Ubuntu 20.04. Maybe I should enter BIOS to enable wireless, but I cannot reach BIOS also. Meanwhile, wireless lamp is shining.

Comment: If you can not even get into BIOS and this computer had crashed maybe you have a serious hardware problem.

Comment: @David Yes, you are right. Keyboard and mousepad are broken, and I use external keyboard and mouse.

Comment: OK you force me to say it replace the computer.